# Is it possible to prompt a permission request from IME on Android without losing focus on the IME itself?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm working on an custom Keyboard that will need to access the micrphone for speech recognition. The system that actually uses speech recognition is already in place, but I wanted to prompt the user to give permission only at the moment they press the microphone button. The issue is that the code I'm used to use

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(...) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
   ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, permissions, 0);
}
```

requires an activity, which I cannot access from an Input Method Service. I actually managed to make it work by creating a new activity and piping all the permissions requests there, but I'd like it to not hide the Keyboard when doing so. Here's how I start the new Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, PermissionsActivity.class); //this being the Input Method Service
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
intent.putExtra(PermissionsActivity.PERMISSIONS_EXTRA, permissionsArray);
```

Is there another, better way to achieve this without creating an Activity or avoiding to hide the keyboard?

Comment: Not really.  An IME is a Service.  You can only request permissions from an Activity.   You could try popping up a transparent Activity and not calling setContentView and finish the Activity as soon as you get a response (positive or negative) on the permission.  It *might* work.

Comment: That is what I do and it is working kinda fine. The only issue is that once the Activity is started, the Keyboard gets hidden and whatever the user chooses to do (either deny the request or grant permission), They have to re-open the keyboard and re-press the button. I want the keyboard to stay visible, capable to respond to the request result. I realize it is just a minor thing which only happens the first time they try to use the speech recognition, but I was wondering if there was a way to achieve this, since other keyboards like gboard manages to do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

I've been catching the permission error and then launching a translucent activity to ask for the permission, something like this:

```
if (errorCode == SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(SpeechInputMethodService.this, PermissionsRequesterActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    SpeechInputMethodService.this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

(See the full code in https://github.com/Kaljurand/K6nele/blob/6aa44a8b6df680f0f8355572ef0cc0bc7224bf00/app/src/main/java/ee/ioc/phon/android/speak/service/SpeechInputMethodService.java#L547-L551)

The keyboard is not hidden in this case. But maybe there is a better way.

Comment: It seems to be we're using basically the same code to start the activity, yet it cloases the keyboard and opens up the settings application. You're saying it doesn't happen to you?

Comment: Yes, in my case it (generally) does not close the keyboard. But it seems to depend also on which activities are in the back stack and how the NEW_TASK flag exactly behaves (which I never fully understood). You can try it with the Kõnele app yourself.